# Broadcastreceiver not receiving triggered Alarm

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have the following problem. I have 2 classes. 1 is called AlarmService and the other is called TimeAlarm which extends BroadcastReceiver.
The App should do the following thing: It should generate a new Alarm to a time specified in the preferences (Which it already does...) also in Logcat i can see how the Alarm gets triggered. But the problem is, that the Notification which should be shown does not show up in the StatusBar.

Here is all the code i have for this:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name="com.ikalma.alarmmanager.TimeAlarm">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

AlarmService.java:

```
private Context context;
private PendingIntent mAlarmSender;

public AlarmService(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    notifyIntent.setClass(context, myActivity.class);
    mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, notifyIntent, 0);
}

public void startAlarm(int stunde, int minute) {
    Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();

    updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, stunde);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, mAlarmSender);
}
```

TimeAlarm.java:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("TEST", "onReceive() called...");
}
```

The Receiver in the Manifest is inside of the  Tag so that should not be a problem.
The problem is, that if i restart my device, it gets called. But not if an Alarm gets triggered.
But the onReceive() method should also be called if an alarm gets triggered, shouldn't it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your intent filter is only listening to boot complete intents and not your own alarm broadcast intent action. update your intent filter so that your broadcast intent is also received (that means for your special case add the action of Intent.ACTION_MAIN to your intent filter)

```
<receiver android:name="com.ikalma.alarmmanager.TimeAlarm">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I added this to my Manifest but it didn't change anything :(
Maybe, is it possible, that i have a SplashScreen which is declared as android.intent.action.MAIN but the SplashScreen does not create the alarm?

Comment: well you can just change the action to something else as long as the action of the intent is the same as the action stated in the intent-filter. You can also try to remove the notifyIntent.setClass(context, myActivity.class); call because you are using a broadcast which is not directed to a specific activity but should be received by broadcast receivers

Comment: Removing the setClass of the notifyIntent was all it took... And of course the intent-filter action which was not set.
Thanks alot for your help!